# validate on empty fields and listing all errors and highlighting all error fields by jquery and show the list of errors on top in zend framework

Tags: jquery, css, zend-framework, validation

i have a form like this

name

i want to do this validation for empty fields when the user clicks on the submit button he should get an error MSG listing all empty fields that are empty on top of the form with the error element if empty being highlighted how can i do this using j query. can anyone help me on this thanks for Ur response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be same what you need.

HTML

```
<div id="msg"></div>
<form class="frm" action="javascript:alert('success!');">
    <div>
      field 1:<textarea class="name" id="required" name="field1"></textarea><br />
      field 2:<textarea class="address" id="not_required" name="field2"></textarea><br />
      field 3:<textarea class="email" id="required" name="field3"></textarea><br />      
      <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".frm").submit(function() {
          var flag = 0;      
          $("#msg").html("");
          $("div #required").each(function(){
            if($(this).val()==""){            
                flag = 1;
                $(this).css("background","red");
                $("#msg").append($(this).attr("name")+" null! <br/>");
            }else
                $(this).css("background","white");
          });
          if(flag==0)
            return true;
          return false;
        }); 
    });
```

Usage: just add the `id="required"` in form elements which you want to validate.

Example on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/blackship/TarGv/4/

Good luck!

Comment: ship actually i want to highlight only some of the required fileds like name email phone and its does not seem to work for textarea sometimes add button also becomes disabled

Comment: @Justin ZEND beginner: I found that you wanna validate the form with jquery, why don't you use jQuery Validator plugin, it's was the best javascript validator I've known until now [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). If you still need my code, I edited it for you. Regards.

Comment: just a small thing: you should probably be using a "required" class, not id; ids should be unique for the DOM.

Comment: @smcphill Thanks for your advice. It's my bad habit in jquery: thought that class & id were the same usage but not same in DOM.